# Set System Preferences using Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, macos, plist, preferences

This is probably trivial, however I couldn't find any information online: How can I set any Apple preference using code? I would like to create a little application for myself that sets certain preferences when I click a button. For instance I would like to turn off Bluetooth and Wi-Fi. As far as I know, these preferences are stored in `/Users/fabian/Library/Preferences/com.apple.*.plist`.

So: how can I change these preferences and make sure they are applied?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [CoreFoundation CFPreferences API](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFPreferences/CFPreferences.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000129i) allows for editing of defaults outside of the current application's defaults domain.

Note that you'll likely need administrative privileges to edit many network related defaults.